# How to pass a variable along with file name in single-line sftp put command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, sftp

I want to sftp to other server and copy a file by changing file name dynamically using shell variable. I want to do this in a single line.

Ex: I want to copy `test.txt` to other server with name `my_test.txt`

```
Dynamic=my
sftp user@hostname:/home/pavan/ <<< 'put test.txt $Dynamic_test.txt'
```

With this file is copied to destination server but copied with name as `$Dynamic_test.txt` and not `my_test.txt`

I also tried this, but no luck

```
sftp user@hostname:/home/pavan/ <<< 'put test.txt $Dynamic\\_test.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the variables, you have to use double quotes (as everywhere else in shell):

```
sftp user@hostname:/home/pavan/ <<< "put test.txt $Dynamic_test.txt"
```